# Attempting to uninstall Carbon Black Bit9 Via a script. Is there a better way to run psession?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to uninstall carbon black protection on a remote agent without PSEXEC. I was informed Pssession is a great replacement for that. All this program does is it pushes an uninstall utility to the box. Disables tamper protection of carbon black, and runs the utility.

When I run the code it appears to be running fine however I noticed once it his the pssession portion the commands are running against my local machine, not the target remote PC.   I am aiming to click a button, enter a PC name and have it all automated.

Is there a better way to run this in Powershell ISE?

When I run the code line by line it executes correctly.

```
        $Computer = "pcname1"

    Enter-PSSession $Computer


    #Copy uninstall Agent to PC Write-Host "Copying uninstall agent to $Computer"

    New-PSDrive -Name UserUNC -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\$Computer\c$\" | out-null 
    Copy-Item -Path  "\\Source\AgentUninstallUtility.exe" -Destination "UserUNC:\Temp"
    Remove-PSDrive UserUNC 
    Write-Host "Item copied to temp"




    Write-Host "Pssesion entered"

    #obtain CLI passwordfrom CB console

    Write-Host "Finding CLI Password"
    $resource = "SOMEWSERVER/omputer?q=name:*" + $env:computername
    $url = "SOMExml"
    $configlist = "C:\Temp\configlistwithdeleteditems.xml"

    [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}

    $wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
    $wc.DownloadFile($url, $configlist)

    $webResponsey = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($resource)
    $webResponsey.Method = "GET"
    $webResponsey.ContentType='application/json; charset=utf-8'
    $webResponsey.Headers.Add("X-Auth-Token", "soemtoken")

    $Response= $webResponsey.GetResponse()
    $ResponseStream = $Response.GetResponseStream()
    $ReadStream = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader $ResponseStream
    $jsonresult = $ReadStream.ReadToEnd()

    $saveme = $jsonresult | Out-String
    $cliPassword = $saveme -replace '(?s).*CLIPassword":"([^"]*)".*', '$1'

    Write-Host "CLI password is " $cliPassword



    Write-Host "Changing directory to Parity Agent"
    cd 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Bit9\Parity Agent'


    .\DasCLI.exe password $cliPassword

    Write-Host "Disabling Tamper protect"
    .\DasCLI.exe tamperprotect 0

    Write-Host "Changing Directory to Temp"
    cd 'C:\Temp\'

    Write-Host "Running Agent Uninstall Utility" 
    & '.\AgentUninstallUtility.exe'+  -password $cliPassword

    Exit-PSSession
```

The remote PC under the pssession should have the agent / files removed.

Comment: Enter-PSSession starts an interactive session with a remote computer, but if I'm getting your question right you need something like Invoke-Command to automate your task.

Comment: I thought invoke-command only passes one line at a time. Is there way to  place all that code I have in between the psesssion statements into an invoke command?

Comment: sure, it can accept script block

Comment: Got it I put it in a script block called $sc and ran  Invoke-Command -Computername $Computer -ScriptBlock $sc

Comment: @Del, please post your final solution. I'd love to wipe CB/Bit9 off of some domain computers... :)